# How to add the Shiprocket in the Dokan wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dokan, shiprocket

I want to customize Dokan plugin to add Shiprocket shipping service. Tried editing Dokan files but couldn't.
Need guidance on properly integrating Shiprocket API with Dokan for fetching rates, creating shipments, modifying templates to display option etc.....